# Wordpress php function does not return value

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to write a PHP function for my WordPress theme that will return the number of categories for a given post. I'm using two files: `functions.php` and `header.php`

Contents of **functions.php**:

```
/**
*   Category count for a given post (post ID) excluding given excludecats (array).  
*   @return number
*/
function bl_cat_count($pid,$excludedcats) {
    $cat_count = 0;
    //$count = 0;
    $categories = get_the_category($pid);
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
        $cat_count++;
        if ( in_array($category->cat_ID, $excludedcats) ) {
            $cat_count--;
        } 
    }
    var_dump($cat_count);
    return $cat_count;
}
```

Contents of **header.php**:

```
$pid = $thumbnail->ID;
$excludedcats = array(1,85);
bl_cat_count($pid,$excludedcats);                          
var_dump($cat_count);
if ( $cat_count > 0 ) {
  // do something
}
```

`var_dump` on the function reveals the correct value. When calling from `header.php` however `var_dump` shows null. Maybe I've been looking at it for too long but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **`header.php`** like this...

```
$cat_count=bl_cat_count($pid,$excludedcats);                          
var_dump($cat_count);
```

### Why it threw null ?

That is because , you are not assigning the value returned by the `bl_cat_count()` to your `$cat_count` variable. Also , `$cat_count` variable's scope is within that function i.e. `bl_cat_count()` !

Comment: expanding upon this, the issue is the scope of the variable. If you defined that variable outside of your `bl_cat_count` function, then you could access it from `header.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
$pid = $thumbnail->ID;
$excludedcats = array(1,85);
bl_cat_count($pid,$excludedcats);                     
var_dump($cat_count);
if ( $cat_count > 0 ) {
  // do something
}
```

So `bl_cat_count` is the function? And `$cat_count` contains the returned result of the function? So where does `$cat_count` get assigned?